# I cannot make the condtion: cart_locked==0 && cart_archive==0 to work. All is deleted at 30 min page reload

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code that is not following the conditions I wanted: All is deleted at page reload.

```
//START CONDITION TO DELETE OLD CARTS
//TASK -> Delete OLD CART  that is NOT FINISHED from database automatically after 30 min
//CONDITION 1 -> Delete OLD CART if cart_locked == 0 && cart_archive==0 ( both conditions must be true.)
//CONDITION 2 -> Do not delete the OLD CART if cart_locked == 1 && cart_archive==0
//CONDITION 3 -> Do not delete the OLD CART if cart_locked == 0 && cart_archive==1
    
    $cart_condition = DB::query ( "SELECT cart_locked,cart_archive FROM cart_details" ); //OK
    foreach ($cart_condition as $row) {
     $cart_locked = $row[ 'cart_locked' ];
     $cart_archive = $row[ 'cart_archive' ];
    }
            

//DELETE anything from cart_details if cart_locked==0 && cart_archive==0,  both conditions must be true.
//mysql_server is local time of server (datetime) where cart is created this is the time that trigger the +30 minutes deletion after reload.
        
    if (($cart_locked == 0 ) && ($cart_archive == 0 )) {
    DB::query ("DELETE FROM cart_details WHERE `mysql_server` < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE ");
    }
```

//PROBLEM: I cannot make the conditions I wanted to be able work properly. Whatever I do, All is deleted from cart_details table at 30 minutes page reload
if cart_locked == 1 && cart_archive==0 ---> Nothing should deleted at 30min page reload
if cart_locked == 0 && cart_archive==1 ---> Nothing should deleted at 30min page reload
if cart_locked == 0 && cart_archive==0 ---> All should be deleted at 30min page reload, That what I want to achieve here.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: add the conditions to your query.  WHERE cart_locked = 0 AND WHERE cart_archived = 0

Comment: What does the column `mysql_server` contain? If it's date ot time wouldn't it be a good idea to give it a name that reflects that?

Comment: Thanks for the advice; I will change the column name to mysql_server_time (datetime) because it's reflecting the local time of the server, not the local time of the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing stuff that you just don't need to do.

Your code is retrieving a list of values with no identifier, then you're iterating over the result set, presumably to delete the rows you retrieved in the first query.

Your code simply doesn't do that.

In any case, there's no need. Iterating over a result set to run individual queries based on that data is almost always unnecessary. You can perform the whole operation with one query:

```
//START CONDITION TO DELETE OLD CARTS
//TASK -> Delete OLD CART  that is NOT FINISHED from database automatically after 30 min
//CONDITION 1 -> Delete OLD CART if cart_locked == 0 && cart_archive==0 ( both conditions must be true.)
//CONDITION 2 -> Do not delete the OLD CART if cart_locked == 1 && cart_archive==0
//CONDITION 3 -> Do not delete the OLD CART if cart_locked == 0 && cart_archive==1

 DB::query ("DELETE FROM cart_details WHERE (`mysql_server` < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) and (`cart_locked` = 0) and (`cart_archived` = 0) ");
```

**Note:** I'm not sure about that column `mysql_server`. Does it really contain a DateTime value related to the cart? Surely you could think of a better name for it!